# Proving $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C^c) = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) - \mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C)$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I can easily deduce from a Venn diagram that $$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C^c) = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) - \mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C)$$
However, I am struggling to prove this. I attempted to start with applying the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle (both with IEP for 2 sets with $(A \cap B)$ and $C^C$ and IEP for 3 sets), but was not able to get any meaningful progress.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could also define $D=A\cap B$ and deduce the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X = A\cap B$. We want to prove that $\Bbb{P}(X\cap C^c) = \Bbb{P}(X) - \Bbb{P}(X\cap C)$.

Of course $X\cap C^c$ and $X\cap C$ are disjoint, so

$$\Bbb{P}(X\cap C^c) + \Bbb{P}(X\cap C) = \Bbb{P}((X\cap C^c)\cup (X\cap C)) = \Bbb{P}(X)$$

as we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Not only do I agree with the other responses, but if these responses had not
been made, then I would not post the following as an *answer*.  Whenever possible,
I favor stretching your intuition to intuitively grasp the problem.

In this case, I would consider three sets:

Let set $S \equiv (A \cap B \cap C^{c}).$ 
Let set $T \equiv (A \cap B).$ 
Let set $U \equiv (A \cap B \cap C).$

I would approach the problem as follows:

Given any element $x$,

$x ~\in ~S \iff $

$\left\{ (x ~\in ~T) \wedge (x ~\not\in ~U)
\right\}.$

First, I would prove the above two way implication.

Then, I would notice that $U$ is a subset of $T$. 
This means that the number of elements in $S$ equals 
the number of elements in $T$ minus the number of elements in $U$.

Again, to emphasize, the other responses to your query get **priority**, re
solving the problem.  The sole point of my answer is: since you already have
the benefit of the other responses, this is the opportunity for my response to
stretch your intuition.

Comment: Thank you, this helps with intuition and connecting the set notation I am used to to more 'formal' notation